# Load Python scripts into memory when running multiple Python scripts from bash script

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script that looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
{
    var1='stuff'
    var2='more stuff'

    cd path/to/package &&
    python setup.py install &&

    printf "Ok, we're gonna run this bad boy" &&
    (
        printf "Training" &&
        python -u script1.py "${var1}" "${var2}" &&
        printf "Testing" &&
        python -u script2.py "${var1}"
    ) 2>&1 | tee log.txt

    exit
}
```

The bash script runs `script1.py` and when that finishes it runs `script2.py`.

**Setup:**

`script1.py` reads some data through some methods defined in other Python scripts, then creates an instance of the class defined in `script3.py` and calls a `train()` method in that class. This `train()` method **runs for several hours**. When this `train()` method returns, `script1.py` also returns.

`script2.py` reads some data through some methods defined in other Python scripts, then creates an instance of the class defined in `script3.py` and calls a `test()` method in that class. This `test()` method **runs for several hours**. When this `test()` method returns, `script2.py` also returns.

`script3.py` and the Python scripts that do the data reading are part of a Python package.

`script3.py` looks like this:

```py
class MyClass():

    some_var = '' # Enum value

    def __init__(self):
        print('Initialized this bad boy')

    def train(self, param1, param2):
        # some code goes here, uses class variable some_var

    def test(self, param1, param2):
        # some code goes here, uses class variable some_var
```

**My flow is as following:**

1. I edit the source code in `script3.py` where I change class variable `some_var`.
2. I run the bash script. (notice the script first runs `python setup.py install`)
3. I edit the source code in `script3.py` where I change the same class variable.
4. I run the bash script. (notice the script first runs `python setup.py install`, also notice that this is **started before the `train()` method returns**)
5. Repeat this several times.

**What I expect to happen:**

I expect that when I run the bash script, the bash script and the Python scripts are loaded into memory and then executed as needed. Specifically:

- the `train()` method from `script3.py` runs with value of `some_var` then returns, `script1.py` also returns
- the `test()` method from `script3.py` runs with the same value of `some_var` then returns, `script2.py` also returns

**What actually happens:**

Let's say I run my bash script 3 times within several minutes. Due to the `train()` method needing several hours to execute, by the time execution reaches the `test()` method, the class variable `some_var` is changed to the last edit of the source code, so all 3 runs use the same value of `some_var`, specifically the value set in the last edit, before running the bash script for the 3rd time.

<s>**A quick fix:**</s>

A quick fix would be to edit `script3.py` to look like this:

```py
class MyClass():

    some_var = 'value1' # Enum value

    def __init__(self):
        print('Initialized this bad boy')

    def train(self, param1, param2):
        self.some_var = 'value1'
        # some code goes here, uses class variable some_var

    def test(self, param1, param2):
        self.some_var = 'value1'
        # some code goes here, uses class variable some_var
```

<s>However, this would be poor code quality and also impractical, since now I'd have to change `some_var` in 3 places before each run of the bash script.</s> On second thought, this wouldn't work. It would behave the same, always use the value from the last edit.

**Question:**

What would be a better way to achieve this?
I'm thinking there has to be a way with loading the Python scripts into memory during the whole execution of the bash script.

Limitations (due to this being part of a bigger project):

- I cannot pass extra parameters in the `train()` or `test()` methods of `script3.py` from `script1.py` or `script2.py`.
- I cannot pass command line arguments to `script3.py`.

Comment: Can you combine the 2 scripts into 1?

Comment: @IainShelvington Technically yes, but that wouldn't help, because the methods from `script3.py` are not called directly from `script1.py` and `script2.py`. There are some abstractions in place due to this being part of a bigger project and I cannot modify those. I believe your idea was to create 1 instance of the class defined in `script3.py` and then just call the methods on that instance. This wouldn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Why not make the scripts take `some_var` as an input, so you don't have to edit the python scripts each time and can just edit the bash script?

Comment: @Alex script1 and script2 do not import the class from script3? My idea was to combine script 1 and 2

Comment: You said `script3` is from a python package. You could also set up separate `venv`s (or `virtualenv` if you're stuck on python2) for the bash scripts to run in, and install `script3` separately to each `venv`, and edit the source code separately for each version you have. Seems much easier to just make the bash script provide the variable for you, though.

Comment: @IainShelvington No, they do not. They call some intermediary objects that figure out what classes to call (in this case it would be the class in `script3.py`). There are several classes with the same skeleton, each having a `train()` and a `test()` method. So I cannot change that structure.

Comment: @jeremysprofile I agree with you that it would be ideal to pass an argument from the bash script to the 2 Python scripts that would then pass it to `script3.py`. However, due to architecture constraints, I cannot make that happen.

Comment: @jeremysprofile I'm using `conda` with Python 3.6.8, so the idea with running the scripts in different environments is technically feasible. However, it would be a bigger hassle than doing the quick fix that I mentioned in the post. I need about 30 runs, so managing 30 environments would be a bit much I think. Appreciate the suggestion though!

Comment: On second thought, the proposed quick fix in the post wouldn't work. It's the same issue, the last edited version would always be used.

Comment: @IainShelvington Your idea worked (of combining the 2 scripts into 1). It wasn't immediately clear to me, due to the abstractions in place, but I now realize that regardless of that, I would still have ALL the necessary classes initialized when I run the bash scripts, due to the 2 scripts now being combined into 1. Thank you! If you'd like to write your comment as an answer, I'd gladly mark it as accepted answer.